# Can we launch instance from Custom AMI using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I was launching the AWS EC2 from custom AMI named as 'test-ami' using terraform .But i was getting below error for the same .As in the main.tf file first custom ami would be created from known server passing source_instance_id , and then ec2 would be created from this custom AMI .Error is

Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidAMIID.Malformed: Invalid id: "test-ami.id" (expecting "ami-...")
status code: 400, request id: 1afd98e1-9d5a-4b1e-b81b-beb24c3da789

on main.tf line 31, in resource "aws_instance" "test-server3":
31: resource "aws_instance" "test-server3" {

Can we created ec2 via custom AMI name as AMI ID is not known to me ?

Comment: Can you show the actual code?

Comment: resource "aws_ami_from_instance" "test-ami" {
  name               = "test-ami"
  source_instance_id = "i-00f72c2be85b6c450"
}

resource "aws_instance" "test-server3" {
  ami = "test-ami.id"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = "subnet-0ab209a91658784cc"
  key_name      = "terraform"
  tags = {
    Name = "test-server3"
  }
}

Comment: Edit question with correctly formatted code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test-server3` should be:

```
resource "aws_instance" "test-server3" { 

    ami = aws_ami_from_instance.test-ami.id
     
    instance_type = "t2.micro" 
    subnet_id = "subnet-0ab209a91658784cc" 
    key_name = "terraform" 
    tags = { 
        Name = "test-server3" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, the answer was helpful and i accept it and appreciate your full support to it .Thanks a lot .

Comment: @AnkitK Thanks, but you have to press a "tick" button under upvote/downvotes to accept the answer.

Comment: It is done, can we have same security group attached to the ec2 launched via custom AMI , that ec2 was having originally , In my case default S.G is getting attached .

Comment: @AnkitK Not directly. You would have to create a launch template or launch configuration with all these details. Then you launch instances from the template/configuration.

Comment: @Marchin Is there any way i can get the newly created instance status check via terraform output ??

Comment: @AnkitK Sorry, not sure what do you mean. You can make new question about this with relevant details.

Comment: Can we get status 2/2 in the output of terraform for newly created instance ?